# Having a continue in a default case in a switch statement

Tags: java, switch-statement

If I had this:

```
do {
    int x = scannerScan.nextInt();

    switch(x)
    {
        case 1:
            System.out.println("Stuff");
            break;
        case 2:
            System.out.println("Pink cows are fluffy and can fly.");
        default:
            continue;
    }
}
while(true);
```

What would happen if the default case were to be reached? I tried to find stuff on the internet and Stackoverflow, but could not find anything about a continue in the default case that had to do with the Java language.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**[continue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html)** statement in the loop

> The continue statement skips the current iteration of a `for`, `while` ,
>   or `do-while` loop. The unlabeled form skips to the end of the innermost
>   loop's body and evaluates the boolean expression that controls the
>   loop. [...]

In your code the loop `while(true);` will continue.
The statement makes no effect on the `switch` code block.

Comment: It makes sense. I was in a bit of hurry, so I couldn't think of a good boolean condition. But, yes this makes sense.

Comment: By the way, when you quote from places you should attribute it.

Comment: @Radiodef thanks for the tip, quoted source is [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html)

Answer (score 8):

`continue` statements in `switch` statements are not special. It would jump to the loop condition (the end of the loop body), just as it would if it was inside the loop but outside the `switch`.

In this particular code snippet, it effectively does nothing.

Answer (score 6):

Compare [`break` statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.15):

> A `break` statement attempts to transfer control to the innermost enclosing **`switch`**, **`while`**, **`do`**, or **`for`** statement …

With [`continue` statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.16):

> A `continue` statement attempts to transfer control to the innermost enclosing **`while`**, **`do`**, or **`for`** statement …

Thus, `continue` refers to the `do...while` loop, and:

> … then immediately ends the current iteration and begins a new one.